# UICollectionReusableView set its height inside the xib file

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, interface-builder, xib

Imagine  i have a UICollectionView returning an headerView, theres a way to set its height inside the xib? I tried setting top and bottom contraint from a label to the view:
[image]

So i want in this case the headerView returned from collectionView:kind:indexPath to be of height 25+labelHeight+25 instead of whatever value is returned in referenceSizeForHeaderInSection or collectionView.collectionViewLayout.headerSize